# jQuery - Simultaneous hover actions on multiple CSS classes

Tags: jquery, hover, toggleclass, oocss

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.button').hover(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('button-hover',200);
    },function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('button-hover',200);
    });
});
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.button-rounded').hover(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('button-rounded-hover',200);
    },function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('button-rounded-hover',200);
    });
});
```

---

```
<div class="button">Add class `button-hover` to this `div` on mouse over.</div>
<div class="button button-rounded">Add class `button-hover` and 
    class `button-rounded-hover` to this `div` on mouse over.</div>
```

---

On the second `div`, it takes 400 ms to do the whole animation: 200 for the `button-hover` toggle, and then another 200 for the `button-rounded-hover` toggle. **How do I perform these toggles simultaneously?**

Notes:

- I'm using OOCSS, so `button-rounded` extends `button`, and `button-rounded-hover` extends `button-hover`. I don't want to define `button-rounded-hover` almost exactly like `button-hover` because that wouldn't be very DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) so that's why I'm using two classes and two hover calls on the second `div`.
- Both actions need to take 200ms. I don't want to make either of them 0 (instantaneous).

Comment: Simultaneous? Do you mean you want the two animations to respond to the same event? As it stands, your code establishes two handlers for two separate, non-nested (and hence non-bubbling) events.

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot: yes, I want the two classes to be added at the same time, when the user mouses over the element.

Comment: So mousing over either element animates both elements?

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot the 2nd div has both classes, so the first handler applies to both. From what I understood, the OP wants to let the 1st behave as it is now, but the second to perform both transitions (button-hover and button-rounded-hover) simultaneously. Right now, mousing over the 2nd activates both handlers, one at a time.

Comment: @mgibsonbr Yes, I was being a bit slow. If I now understand correctly, my answer below should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If every element that has `.button-rounded` class also have `.button` class (that's what I understood by "button-rounded extends button"), you should only add a hover handle to button, and select the class to be toggled based on whether or not your element has button-rounded class. Example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.button').hover(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass(
            ($(this).hasClass('button-rounded') ? 'button-rounded-hover ' : '') +
            'button-hover',
            200
        );
    });
});
```

[toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) also accpets a list of classes separated by spaces, so you can toggle multiple classes simultaneously that way.

Note: since both "over" and "out" functions are equals, you can use a single one and it will apply to both events.

Comment: But on `button-rounded` elements, I need to have **both** classes added, because `button-rounded-hover` extends `button-hover`. If I only added `button-rounded-hover` then all of the styles in `button-hover` wouldn't be applied.

Comment: answer updated. toggleClass accepts space-separated class names, such as "button-hover button-rounded-hover". Passing that to toggleClass will make both animations simultaneous.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.button').hover(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('button-hover',200);
    });
    $('.button-rounded').hover(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('button-hover button-rounded-hover',200);
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="button">Add class `button-hover` to this `div` on mouse over.</div>
<div class="button-rounded">Add class `button-hover` and class `button-rounded-hover` to this `div` on mouse over.</div>
```

Note removal of class `button` from the second div, which may require redefinition of the two classes' CSS.

Comment: See my above note on OOCSS. The second div needs to have both classes.

Comment: Have to confess, I've never heard of OOCSS.

Comment: Basically the idea is that there are certain rules that all buttons have. Some buttons, of the rounded variety, have a few extra rules. Instead of defining the common rules in both classes (Repeating Yourself), I only define the extra rules in `button-rounded` and then apply both classes to the element. Object-oriented CSS.

Comment: So OOCSS isn't a different technology, it's just an exploitation of the cascade?

Comment: Exactly. It's a paradigm, not a language. If I were on my computer instead of my iPhone, I'd cite a few resources. Google "OOCSS" and "Nicole Sullivan".

Comment: If I understand correctly, then "OOCSS" is a very very very misleading term. In normal OO parlance, "extend" means "inherit plus differences", whereas here it appears to mean just "differences".

Comment: I think the solution is actually quite simple. You need to avoid using className `button` for both styling and as a jQuery selector. By introducing another means of selection (eg. id(s) or additional non style-related className(s)), then you can reintroduce className 'button' to the second div and adjust the selectors in my code above.

Comment: 'In normal OO parlance, "extend" means "inherit plus differences", whereas here it appears to mean just "differences".' --- The "inherit" part of OOCSS comes from the process of adding two classes to an element. Yes, you're right, the 'subclass' doesn't *inherit* the rules from its 'superclass' (**[maybe it should](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8830319/is-it-better-to-import-a-pre-written-rule-for-each-css-style-or-to-write-your-ow)...**) but the element to which those classes are added *does* inherit those rules.